# Remap arrow keys vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to make my arrow keys in vim useless to get used to <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd>.

After adding a few lines to my `.vimrc` file everything worked but the insert mode remap.

```
nnoremap <Down> :echo "No down for you!"<CR>
vnoremap <Down> :<C-u>echo "No down for you!"<CR>
inoremap <Down> :<C-o> echo "No down for you!"<CR>

nnoremap <Up> :echo "No up for you!"<CR>
vnoremap <Up> :<C-u>echo "No up for you!"<CR>
inoremap <Up> :<C-o>echo "No up for you!"<CR>

nnoremap <Left> :echo "No left for you!"<CR>
vnoremap <Left> :<C-u>echo "No left for you!"<CR>
inoremap <Left> :<C-o>echo "No left for you!"<CR>

nnoremap <Right> :echo "No right for you!"<CR>
vnoremap <Right> :<C-u>echo "No right for you!"<CR>
inoremap <Right> :<C-o>echo "No Right for you!"<CR>
```

The problem is, every time one arrow key is pressed it inserts the following string into my file:

> :echo "No **** for you!

Comment: its better to get used to hjkl, it is the default for a reason, I am also quite new to vim but hjkl default really helps. I recently discovered that the j and k keys are also the default to scroll a pdf document in `evince`. So the habit does benefit outside vim and to get used to it here is a [fun way](http://vim-adventures.com/)

Comment: Thanks @Imran , already did the vim advetures. It's a nice way to begin.

Comment: In your insert mode mappings `<C-o>` should come after `:` so the right one for Left key for example is `inoremap <Left> <C-o>:echo "No left for you!"<CR>`

Comment: if the visual and normal mappings are the same you can use only `noremap` which affects both modes !

Comment: Already tried that @dNitro and got the same error. At this point my hope is beginning to vanish.

Comment: Thanks @Meninx, will save a couple lines!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have the [vi.SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for Vim questions, it is always better to post directly there.  Anyhow:

Sardorbek's answer is correct, mapping to `<nop>` *is* the right solution. i.e. this:

```
noremap <Up> <nop>
noremap <Down> <nop>
noremap <Left> <nop>
noremap <Right> <nop>

inoremap <Up> <nop>
inoremap <Down> <nop>
inoremap <Left> <nop>
inoremap <Right> <nop>
```

---

Yet, the reason that your `inoremap` was printing the lines into the file is because you did use `<c-o>` after `:` at the beginning of your mappings, therefore the normal mode command that was being run was `e` (not `:echo`).  I believe that the lines you were seeing were actually:

```
:cho "No **** for you!
```

And not

```
:echo "No **** for you!
```

Moreover, `<c-o>` allows for only one normal mode command but you need two: echo the message, and negate the arrow key movement.

In essence, the following is *horrible* (really horrible, please do not do this) but would have worked:

```
inoremap <Down> <esc>:echo "No down for you!"<CR>ki
inoremap <Up> <esc>:echo "No up for you!"<CR>ji
inoremap <Left> <esc>:echo "No left for you!"<CR>li
inoremap <Right> <esc>:echo "No Right for you!"<CR>hi
```

In general, using `<esc>` is preferable to `<c-o>` and `c-u` (in visual mode) wherever possible.

Comment: Why is `<esc>` preferable to `<c-o>` and `<c-u>`?

Comment: @TomHale - I guess I'll argue it is like adding curly brackets to `if` statements in C-like languages even if the `if` has only a single statement.  Later you will add more statements and forget that you do not have the curly braces and wonder why the second statement always executes.  `c-o`/`c-u` allows for only one command but it is easy to forget that and several weeks later add another one.